# Using song for interval training or not

Tags: intervals, ear-training, self-learning, hearing, learning-resources

When learning the intervals, is it bad using song as a reference? I mean I wanna get as good as possible and get them on instinct rather than a song reference. It would be also be less work if can skip memorising all the songs.

Comment: I vtc, but will answer the dupe soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think: you need to memorize the intervals BEFORE doing any "interval training" with a song. But yes, doing that with a song is a good idea, because it actually gives you practical experience rather than just going through a bunch of exercises in a book.

So long story short, just memorize the intervals (what they are) AND THEN start practicing them in the context of songs. The reason is, as you say, you want to be able to identify them in any given context, so memorizing them first hopefully will accomplish this.